# How to include dependencies when publish the library to bintray in android

Tags: android, maven, android-gradle-plugin, pom.xml, bintray

I'm new to publish own library in android.
I created my own library and uploaded it to bintray. My library depends several third party libraries. When I see pom.xml file, there are dependency information.
But when I add my library to test project gradle, it didn't import its dependencies. So I had to add it manually test project's gradle. How can I import dependency module automatically when I add my library to test project's gradle?
Is there anyone that can solve this? My library is on binary's maven repository.
I find expert in this scope now.

Comment: I'm an iOS engineer. When we use cocoa pod, it downloads everything its dependency. But I can't do it in android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include your library as a [**transitive dependency**](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:transitive_dependency_management). Your `build.gradle` should have something like this:

```
compile('com.example.your.library:0.1.0@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks. I tried this solution but I got failed.