# Why I can't add aar file to our library project and distribute it without aar?

Tags: maven, android-library, bintray, android-module

we are getting really frustrated both financially and also in our project level. The root problem is that we have build an android library project, which uses another aar as a dependency. The clients which integrate our library have to manually include the aar and it does not work in all cases..

​

I can't understand why does [**https://bintray.com/**](https://bintray.com/)  does not allow to publish library with added aar file inside of it? We have tried to create a same maven and even publish additional library, but client still need to include **both** libraries and not a single one..

Android team endorses multi module approach, so why there are no tools to easily integrate library, which has **another library as a dependency?**

Maybe someone had solved this issue or knows how to do what I have done?

Comment: Have you tried adding the dependency library in your pom file? If you do this, you don't have to ship both libraries. Gradle will take care of it.

Comment: How can I do that? I am using a bintray plugin for creating our Pom file:
https://github.com/novoda/bintray-release
I did not found any way for manually generating aar

Comment: I haven't tried it. Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/41623377/1496502